# scrollTo changes direction on window resize

Tags: jquery, scrollto, direction, window-resize

http://avalon.eaw.com

i've got a horizontal scrollTo script running which works great. however if the window is re-sized for any reason the scroll direction changes from horizontal to vertical. anyone have an idea how to fix?

i'm relatively new to jQuery so please be gentle :)

Comment: @casperOne what are you talking about? i posted the link to the site with the code in question, also so you can look at the site and see the behavior in action. all the requirements to answer the question are there and imho could not be any more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On resize the following function is executed:

```
function resizePanel() {

    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

    $('#wrapper, .page').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('#stage').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);

}
```

This effectively restrains a width on `#stage` which was already set by the scroll plugin (I'm guessing; or css styles)... and I also think you don't need to set the heights for all the panels..

In fact I'm not sure why this function exists, try removing it completely, or partially (without the `#stage` css set or `#wrapper, .page` css set)

Comment: removing the #stage set worked perfectly! thank you! i got this script off a tutorial website so fully understand what all of them did. i'm learning, though. gotta start somewhere!